# JOptionpane implement in a JDialog, call once, but that run repeatedly. Why?

Tags: java, joptionpane, jdialog

There are 2 files in the source folder to four times a JOptionPane.

Previously, it was 5 files in the source folder, the message appeared seven times.
It is based on the number of appearances does not depend on the number of files copied.

Caller code:

```
JButton btnCopyAllFiles = new JButton("Copy All Files");
btnCopyAllFiles.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
    {
        final JDialog dialog = new JDialog(WebAdmin.this, "Copy files", true);
        dialog.setSize(500, 80);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        GridBagLayout gbl_panel = new GridBagLayout();
        GridBagConstraints gBC = new GridBagConstraints();
        //gBC.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        panel.setLayout(gbl_panel);

        final JTextField txtTargetDir = new JTextField(30);
        txtTargetDir.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 12));
        gBC.insets = gridBagInsets;
        gBC.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gBC.gridx = 1;
        gBC.gridy = 0;
        panel.add(txtTargetDir, gBC);

        JButton btnBrowseTarget = new JButton("Browse");
        btnBrowseTarget.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
            {
                JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
                chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
                chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
                chooser.showOpenDialog(WebAdmin.this);
                File ff = chooser.getCurrentDirectory();
                File fl = chooser.getSelectedFile();
                String filename_last = fl.getName();
                String filename_first = ff.getAbsolutePath();

                txtTargetDir.setText(filename_first + "/" + filename_last + "/");
            }
        });         
        gBC.insets = gridBagInsets;
        gBC.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gBC.gridx = 2;
        gBC.gridy = 0;
        gBC.gridwidth = 2;
        panel.add(btnBrowseTarget, gBC);

        JButton btnOK = new JButton("OK");
        btnOK.setToolTipText("All files copied to the specified folder");
        btnOK.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                try {
                    File source = new File(Functions.readStoreFile());
                    File target = new File(txtTargetDir.getText());
                    Functions.copyDirectory(source, target);
                    dialog.dispose();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        gBC.insets = gridBagInsets;
        gBC.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gBC.gridx = 3;
        gBC.gridy = 1;
        gBC.gridwidth = 1;
        panel.add(btnOK, gBC);

        dialog.add(panel);
        dialog.pack();
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

Method call place:

```
JButton btnOK = new JButton("OK");
        btnOK.setToolTipText("All files copied to the specified folder");
        btnOK.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                try {
                    File source = new File(Functions.readStoreFile());
                    File target = new File(txtTargetDir.getText());
                    Functions.copyDirectory(source, target);
                    dialog.dispose();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

Called method:

```
public static void copyDirectory(File sourceLocation , File targetLocation) {
    boolean isOK = true;
    if (sourceLocation.isDirectory()) {
        if (!targetLocation.exists()) {
            targetLocation.mkdir();
        }

        String[] children = sourceLocation.list();
        for (int i=0; i<children.length; i++) {
            copyDirectory(new File(sourceLocation, children[i]),
                new File(targetLocation, children[i]));
        }
    } 
    else {
        try {
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(sourceLocation);
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(targetLocation);

            // Copy the bits from instream to outstream
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                out.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
            in.close();
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            isOK = false;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if (isOK){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Files copied success!", "Copy finished!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will produce one JOptionPane for each file copied that fail.

Probably, you are trying to copy the directory special "..".
Print the list of files to certify that.

Check the stacktrace for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve! A copy of each was successful, but because the method itself recursively called JOptionPane so the number of files + 1 times appeared.

```
btnOK.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        try {
            ...
            if ( Functions.copyDirectory(source, target) ){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Files copied success!", "Copy finished!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
            dialog.dispose();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});

public static boolean copyDirectory(File sourceLocation , File targetLocation) {
    boolean isOK = true;
    try{
            ...
            ...
            in.close();
            out.close();
            isOK = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            isOK = false;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return isOK;
}
```